# Android Opengraph Like Button Implementation

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-layout

I have to integrate facebook like button in my android application. I have created a facebook page, and from the android application when user clicks the like button should likes the facebook page. I used facebook social plugin in web view and worked fine. Now I like to change the facebook social plugin like button icon/style to a new custom like button.

I think using custom like button with social plugin will cause branding issues (http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php). So I decided to go with opengraph api. I am new to opengraph.

**I would like to know how to configure opengraph settings in facebook app page for like action?**

**I have no server for embedding opengraph objects, so how do I sent opengraph like request to facebook from my android application?**

**What are the resource bundle key values to be sent to facebook sdk?**

Thanks in advance

@nish

Comment: I would also like to add the Like button. If you get succeed, pls post the code.

Comment: Is there already a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook **recently update** its SDK and it now provides an **implementation for Like button** ([There is a news about it](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/10/02/mobilelike/)), take a look **[there](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button)** to get a tutorial about that.